# Error/Bug when changing auto scaling configuration of AWS Beanstalk worker tier environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an application/worker running inside AWS Beanstalk using the worker tier environment.  When I go into Configuration -> Scaling -> Scaling Trigger and try to change the configuration to one based on `HealthyHostCount` or `UnhealthyHostCount` or `Latency`, the changes are not saved and I receive two errors: `Failed to deploy configuration.` and `Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [AWSEBLoadBalancer] in the Resources block of the template`. It looks as if it does not detect the Load Balancer for some reason.

I have tried recreating the environment and uploading another application and it does not work either.  I think it is a bug with the Worker 1.1 environment of AWS Beanstalk.

Does anyone know how to solve this or have any idea of what can be wrong in the configuration?

Comment: Are you using the sample app? Do you have any ebextensions? Is it a single instance environment? Do you face the same issue with Worker Tier 1.0?

Comment: I edited my question.  I troubleshooted the problem even deeper and the issue only happens when you try to use a trigger based on `HealthyHostCount`, `UnhealthyHostCount` or `Latency`.  It also happens in the SampleApp and with WorkerTier 1.0.  I don't have any ebextensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worker Tier environments in Elastic Beanstalk do not require a load balancer. Hence when you create a Worker environment you do not get an ELB. You get EC2 instances which belong to an AutoScaling Group. You cannot define Scaling Triggers based on ELB metrics. That is why you are seeing the error.

Comment: Well, then it is confusing because, on worker environment creation it asks for a "heartbeat" endpoint as it does with web tiers.  Also, it shouldn't include those options if there is no load balancer.  Moreover, how does it know if the worker is healthy without a load balancer?

Comment: You can find documentation on how the health of worker environment is determined here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.healthstatus.html. Essentially the daemon running on the EC2 instances pings the web application on the endpoint if specified otherwise it attempts a TCP connect. Based on this ElasticBeanstalk determines the health of your environment.  The daemon additionally depends on whether it can successfully poll the SQS queue or not to set the health.